# Ghost modules in modules.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Here is my modules.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/../...iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/../...iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/7Wonders.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/7Wonders.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/../AFLib/AFLib.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/../AFLib/AFLib.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$USER_HOME$/Documents.iml" filepath="$USER_HOME$/Documents.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$USER_HOME$/Documents.iml" filepath="$USER_HOME$/Documents.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$USER_HOME$/Documents.iml" filepath="$USER_HOME$/Documents.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/../MultiConnect/MultiConnect.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/../MultiConnect/MultiConnect.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/../MultiConnect/lib/MultiConnect-lib.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/../MultiConnect/lib/MultiConnect-lib.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/_7Wonders/_7Wonders.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/_7Wonders/_7Wonders.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/../AFLib/lib/lib.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/../AFLib/lib/lib.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

"7 Wonders" is the app, "MultiConnect" and "AFLib" are my libraries.
The stuff starting with `$USER_HOME` is completely unneeded: there is no Documents.iml file.   I delete these lines, Android Studio adds them back.  Then it complains that it can't open a module... 2 modules... 3 modules... and so on, until I delete those lines manually again.  If I click on "Details" in the error message, it offers to remove those modules from the project, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.  I even tried to make the modules.xml file read-only, but Android Studio complains and refuses to work.

This issue does not affect usability, but seeing that "Error Loading Project" every single time is rather annoying.

I don't need the `...iml` file (the 1st line) either, but at least the Studio doesn't complain about it, and doesn't add several copies of it.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Is there something in your `settings.gradle` that is triggering this?

Comment: like what?  I have 3 `settings.gradle` files.  The "library" ones are simply  `include ':lib'`.  The "app" one has exactly 3 lines, by the number of subprojects.

Comment: I'm not sure, the settings file determines the modules that are considered part of the project.  You probably don't need 3 of them.  Only one is loaded at any given time.

If you do a text search through your project directory do you see any other references to "Documents" ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why this is happening. 
1. Uninstall plugin "Markdown support" from plugins in settings.

Try compiling the whole project before gradle refresh is done. And set gradle settings as "Offline Work".
This will save a lot of time and will also save on re-installation of gradle dependencies. This re-install probably will cause refresh in modules.xml